# Configure bower to install only dist folder

Tags: javascript, git, bower

I am trying to learn tools such as bower/grunt/requirejs  in order to speed up the development process for my website and to make my code more modularized/efficient.  I am currently following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-requirejs-backbone-and-bower-starter-template--net-29211).  How does one make Bower only install the dist folder for my dependencies (setup in my component.json file) instead of the entire Git repository?

Comment: If you're not the developer of the module, maybe bower-installer can help you grab only the parts you want from components: https://scotch.io/tutorials/only-grab-the-files-you-need-while-using-bower

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What you're looking for is the *ignore* property in `bower.json`: https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec

The developer of the module can use the *ignore* attribute to exclude files when the module is downloaded and installed through Bower.

If you are the developer of said module, you can use the *ignore* attribute to exclude everything but the *dist* folder.

If you're not the developer of the module, then there's not much you can do, you will get whatever the developer of the module has deemed significant. In most cases, this is not a problem.

Here's a typical configuration for the *ignore* attribute:

```
{
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "package.json",
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Bower does not provide any option to do that. Mostly because [they have refused to](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/368).

All we are left to is hacky ways to deal with it, like [grunt-wiredep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-wiredep), which doesn't solve the problem in a strict sense.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

From Bower's [api documentation](http://bower.io/docs/api/#consuming-a-package), there doesn't seem to be anything to say "Install just the dist folder".

As you are using Grunt already, you could probably create a task to run after your `bower install` using [grunt-contrib-clean](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean) to remove unwanted files and folders from the `bower_components` folder.

Something like this should remove everything from the `bower_components` folder except `dist` folders:

```
clean : {
    dist : ['bower_components/*/*', '!bower_components/*/dist']
}
```

While looking into this I also found [grunt-bower-task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bower-task) which seems to do exactly that. The only drawback I see to this method is that you have to create the bower.json by hand first and then run the grunt task.

Comment: grunt-bower-task works great. With the "exportOverride" option, can install the `.min` version, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but may help with what you are trying to accomplish.

There are two plugins: [grunt-wiredep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-wiredep) and [grunt-wiredep-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-wiredep-copy) which can help you manage your bower dependencies. These automagically add the dependencies to your HTML, and can then grab the required minified ones and copy them to your dist folder.

I am however struggling with some aspects of this at [How to manage bower dependencies when developing and deploying with grunt and a dist project folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397041/how-to-manage-bower-dependencies-when-developing-and-deploying-with-grunt-and-a)